# CSS3 linear-gadient not working

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I watched [this](http://codepen.io/joshnh/pen/JCGoF) CodePen demo in which CSS3 `linear-gradient` is used to make the color effects, I tried the same `linear-gradient` property at jsFiddle but this CSS3 property was not working in it.

Here is the [CodePen code](http://codepen.io/joshnh/pen/JCGoF) and this is my [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/ShzsV/).

Can anyone explain me that what is the problem behind this or is there any jsFiddle fault or else?

Comment: There is no problem. You have to add prefixes for each browser! See my answer... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you writes `linear-gradient` in CodePen, it **automaticly adds website prefixes** in code (*see screenshot: CodePen code in Firebug*). So, the prefixes which you need:

- `-webkit` for Safari, Chrome, Android browser and mobile Safari
- `-moz` for Firefox
- `-o` for Opera
- `-ms` for IE 10+

See code: **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vule/NURGn/)**

[image: Codepen example code in Firebug]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the colorzilla gradient generator to create gradients.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

You can get the code that will suit to all browsers, just copy paste the generated code for your element css.

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at the Inspector will help you solve such problems fast and easy.
It seems CodePen has some kind of automatic vendor prefixing because the actual styles applied to element look like this:
[image: webkit prefixes]

Doing the same on the jsFiddle site shows that there are no prefixes applied and therefore the whole property is not working (indicated by the warning sign and strike-through):

[image: no prefixes]

Prefixes needed:
`-webkit` for Safari, Chrome, Android
`-moz` for Firefox
`-o` for Opera
`-ms` for IE

For browser compatibility see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)

Handling those prefixes can be a huge pain so you should have a look preprocessors like [less](http://lesscss.org/) or js libraries doing the job: [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/)